# "&& vs if [ $? -ne 0 ] vs set -e" managing child process

Tags: shell-script

I made a master shell that calls many step shells one at a time

```
#!/bin/bash
##I'm the master shell and I'm super important. I should never fail to log.

bash ./step1.sh
bash ./step2.sh
bash ./step3.sh
bash ./step4.sh

...
```

The step shells must not fail before calling the later one.
I'm thinking 3 ways to do it, but I actually don't know what they exactly do.

method 1)

```
bash ./step1.sh &&
bash ./step2.sh &&
bash ./step3.sh &&
bash ./step4.sh &&
...
```

method 2)

```
bash ./step1.sh 

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  bash ./step2.sh 
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  bash ./step3.sh
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    bash ./step4.sh
fi
...
```

method 3)

```
set -e
bash ./step1.sh
bash ./step2.sh
bash ./step3.sh
bash ./step4.sh
...
set +e
```

I need the master script to terminate as soon as one of the `step` scripts fails, and I need to be able to log which step it is that fails.

Which one is the most preferred and which one is the safest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving aside "safest" as you never say anything about what behavior you consider as "safe", and "preferred" as not knowing what your scripts are doing, there may well be "better" ways of achieving what you are trying to do.

Since you need to log a failure in one of the individual steps before exiting your master script, you can't really run the steps under `set -e` or in a chain with `&&` between them.  That is, unless the `step` scripts log failures themselves.

Assuming that it's the master script that needs to log the failure:  The master script needs to be able to run the next script and detect a failure.  It would then need to notify the user of this failure before terminating.

I would probably opt for a variant of your 2nd method:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for step in {1..4}; do
    if ! bash "./step$step.sh"; then
        printf 'Step %s failed, terminating...\n' "$step" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo 'All done, no failures'
```

This loops over the integers 1 through to 4 and executes the appropriate script in each iteration.  If a script fails, it logs this with a diagnostic message to the user and terminates with a non-zero exit status.

Instead of looping over integers, you could obviously use

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for script in ./step*.sh; do
    if ! bash "$script"; then
        printf 'Script "%s" failed, terminating...\n' "$script" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo 'All done, no failures'
```

... which would loop over the actual step scripts (in the order that the filename globbing returns them), or

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for script in ./step{1..4}.sh; do
    if ! bash "$script"; then
        printf 'Script "%s" failed, terminating...\n' "$script" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo 'All done, no failures'
```

to have more control over the exact ordering of the scripts (especially if you have more than 9 scripts).